# avatar cmd, .setImage avatar isn't displayed as a gif

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, gif, avatar

[image: j]

So as you can see in the scrrenshot the link is a .gif but (you cannot see that obvious) the ".setImage" isn't a gif, it is a webp and i wonder why.

Here's my code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'avatar',
    aliases: ['ava', 'profilepic', 'profilepicture'],
    description: 'Displays your own avatar or the avatar of a user you emntioned',
    category: "general",
    usage: 'prefix | avatar | mention',
    run : async (message, client, args) => {
        const Discord = require('discord.js');

        if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
            let embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(color)
                .setTitle(`Your avatar`)
                .setImage(message.author.displayAvatarURL({ format: "png", dynamic: true }))
                .addField(`Link:`, `${message.author.displayAvatarURL({ format: "png", dynamic: true })}`)
            message.channel.send(embed1);
        }
        else{
            const user = message.mentions.users.first()
            let embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(color)
                .setTitle(`${user.username}'s avatar:`)
                .setImage(user.displayAvatarURL({ format: "png", dynamic: true }))
                .addField(`Link:`, `${user.displayAvatarURL({ format: "png", dynamic: true })}`)
            message.channel.send(embed2);
        }
    }
};
```

Would be nice if someone knows why/has a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{ format: "png", dynamic: true }` doesn't really work. Dynamic option means turned into `.gif` if the avatar is animated, else turns back with `png`.
So you don't need to use format option if dynamic option is true.